# Using R to loop through vector and copy some sequences to data.frame

Tags: r, text-mining

I want to search through a vector for the sequence of strings "hello" "world". When I find this sequence, I want to copy it, including the 10 elements before and after, as a row in a data.frame to which I'll apply further analysis.

My problem: I get an error "new column would leave holes after existing columns". I'm new to coding, so I'm not sure how to manipulate data.frames. Maybe I need to create rows in the loop?

This is what I have:

```
df = data.frame()
i <- 1
for(n in 1:length(v))
{

  if(v[n] == 'hello' & v[n+1] == 'world')
  {
    df[i,n-11:n+11] <- v[n-10:n+11]
    i <- i+1
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of the data frame, and/or whatever `v` is, and the desired result.  Also this line `df[i,n-11:n+11] <- v[n-10:n+11]` should be `df[i,(n-11):(n+11)] <- v[(n -10):(n+11)]`

Comment: Makes no sense to go to end of full length of case. If "hello" is at very end then "world" can't very well be present in a non-existent location. And do remember to consider the edge cases of "hello","world" in one of the first or last 10 positions. This can be vectorized and cleaned with `which` and `grepl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps

```
indx <- which(v1[-length(v1)]=='hello'& v1[-1]=='world')
lst <- Map(function(x,y) {s1 <- seq(x,y)
                   v1[s1[s1>0 & s1 < length(v1)]]}, indx-10, indx+11)

len <- max(sapply(lst, length))

d1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, `length<-`, len)))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(496)
v1 <- sample(c(letters[1:3], 'hello', 'world'), 100, replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. I promise to look up the expressions to learn from what you did!